# How do you iterating context variables with forms in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a list of questions and a form that has a corresponding number of answer fields.

```
Example:
    questions = ['What is your favorite color?', 'What is your first car?']
```

How do I display in template, alternating question and answer pair?

```
Desired results:

What is your favorite color?
Answer: [answer_field1]

What is your first car?
Answer: [answer_field2]
```

Currently, my template has this code but it is not displaying correctly.

```
{% load i18n %}

{% block head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

Please answer these questions:
<p>
<p>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

{% for question in questions %}
    {{ question }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
{% endfor %}
```

I don't have control over looping over 'form' because Django does that automatically. I'm not sure how to zip 'form' and 'questions' together to for loop them together.

Comment: Why don't you add the text of each question as a `label` for the form fields?

Comment: @ShangWang Thanks. So my form fields are dynamic.  So I have updated them to this. form.fields['Answer_%s' % i].label = a['question'].  How do you access these in the templates?   Adding this doesn't seem to work. <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}

 {{ form.field.label }}
 {{ form.as_p }}


</table>
<p>

Comment: I thought `{{ form.as_p }}` already renders `label` with `field` together. Look at the example in the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options and check the html `form.as_p` created.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to write a custom templatetag to achieve such task. but before you would do that, you might need to consider these questions

**Does the index of a question in the questionsList correspond with the index of its answer field in the form?**

**Does the length of the questionsList equals the number of fields present in the form?**

**Try this**

> templatetags/mytag.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


def do_question_n_ans(parser, token):
   """
      Usage:
            {% do_question_n_ans_for question in questionsList and ans_field in form.fields %}
   """
   bits = token.contents.split()
   if len(bits) != 8:
      raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("'%s' takes exactly seven arguments" % bits[0])
   if len(bits[3]) != len(bits[7]):
      raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Question list and anwser fields must b of the same length")
   if bits[2] != 'in':
      raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Second argument to '%s' must be 'in'" % bits[0])
   if bits[4] != 'and':
      raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Third argument to '%s' must be 'and'" % bits[0])
   if bits[7] != 'in':
      raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Sixth argument to '%s' must be 'in'" % bits[0])
   return QuestionAnswerFormatNode(bits[1], bits[3], bits[5], bits[7]


class QuestionAnswerFormatNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, question, questionsList, ans_field, fields):
        self.questionsList = questionsList
        self.fields = fields
        self.question = question
        self.ans_field = ans_field

def render(self, context):
    try:
        questionsList = template.resolve_variable(self.questionsList, context)
    except template.VariableDoesNotExist:
        raise template.VariableDoesNotExist
    question_index = questionsList.index(question)
    ans_field = fields[question_index]
    context[self.ans_field] = ans_field
    return ''


register.tag('do_question_n_ans_for', do_question_n_ans)
```

you could then use the tag within your html code

```
{% load mytag %}

{% for question in questionList %}
   {% do_question_n_ans_for question in questionsList and ans_field in form.fields %}
   <p>Question: {{ question }}</p>
   <p>Answer: {{ ans_field }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**Note:**

I presumed you already have the questions and the answer fields arranged in this format in their respective list

['question1', 'question2', 'question3'] and ['answerFieldToQuestion1', 'answerFieldToQuestion2', 'answerFieldToQuestion3'].

you should be able to check out the order of your form fields by printing yourForm.fields.

Please let me know if there are any errors as i didn't test the above code, but i guarantee you it would work just fine

Comment: The length of the question list will always equal the number of fields present in the form.  The answer field take in just character so indexing to the questions is some what arbitrary as long as after the answer is enter, both questions and answers are paired together correctly.